# Conversion of bool type image to uint8

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-thresholding

I used the link below for thresholding of my images.
https://github.com/subokita/Sandbox/blob/master/otsu.py
but my images was grayscale and I didn't as same as the link.
now I want to use the function otsu2 or otsu1

```
img=cv2.imread('E:/tilpixs2/23_1050_450_5.0X/til1.G.png')

rows,cols,channelsNo=shape(img)

# create 256 bins histogram
hist = histogram(img, 256)[0] 

# apply the otsu thresholding
thresh=otsu2(hist,rows*cols)
img2=img>=thresh

plt.imsave("E:/tilpixs2/img2.png", img2)

img2.dtype  #it is boolean
```

To convert img2 to uint8, I did some convertions. Some of them are here"

```
img2.dtype='uint8'
```

or

```
img4=img2.astype(uint8)
```

or

```
npyage = np.array(img2)
img3=img2.np.uint8
```

But when I check the image when saved, the bit depths in properties of image is 32. I'm totally confused, What should I do?
what does 32 in bit depth means?
I want an image of 8 bit int

[This is the properties of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b549C.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.  As long as you specify the `dtype` of your image, then save with `plt.imsave` it should respect the bit depth that it was saved at.  Also, since you're using OpenCV you should use `cv2.imwrite` instead.  It's usually not a good idea to mix packages when dealing with image I/O.

Comment: I used cv2.imwrite too. But the image saved with 32 bit depth again.

Comment: This is a classic case of PEBKAC. Voting to close as your error is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that plt is an object reference to Matplotlib.pyplot, the module doesn't respect color depth for it's `imsave` call. OpenCV's imsave will respect the datatype. See the documentation for pyplot's image save call here:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave.html

```
img = cv2.imread('E:/tilpixs2/23_1050_450_5.0X/til1.G.png')

rows, cols, channelsNo = shape(img)

# create 256 bins histogram
hist = histogram(img, 256)[0]

# apply the otsu thresholding
thresh = otsu2(hist, rows * cols)
img2 = img >= thresh

img3 = img2.astype(uint8)

# Choose one of the options below depending on required format

# Save all 3 channels as a 24bpp grayscale image
cv2.imwrite("E:/tilpixs2/img2.png", img3)

# Save a single channel as a 8bpp grayscale image
cv2.imwrite("E:/tilpixs2/img2.png", img3[:,:,1])
```

Comment: Thank you,but I checked it before, the cv2.imwrite doesn't save with 8 bit depth

Comment: Yes, OpenCV *does* save with 8-bit depth.

Comment: @diana Are you referring to the image format reading 24bpp instead of 8bpp? It's 8 bit depth, but the 24bpp you're seeing is a 3-channel grayscale each with the same 8bit value in each channel. See my edits above and choose the save function that you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you @Jon,
I will check it in my codes.